# Can a company have a "sector"? "The company's meat sector produces over 400 tonnes/day"

Tags: phrase-usage, terminology, translation

I have a Russian sentence:

> Общая производительность **мясной отрасли** компании превышает 400 тонн в сутки.

Which, put literally, translates into

> In total, the company's **meat sector** produces more than 400 tonnes per day.

But it feels to me like in English a company cannot have a **sector**, and it's better to use **meat-production branch** or something like this. It feels like in English a **meat sector** can only be part of an economony.

Am I right, or maybe not, and a company can have a "sector" to itself? The Russian company in question is a big regional (south of Russia) corporation with many facitilies, some of which produce meat and meat products.

Comment: Good question, how about meat department?

Comment: Or meat **division** or meat **branch**.

Comment: Both [***meat section*** and ***meat sector***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+meat+sector%2Cthe+meat+section&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20meat%20sector%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20meat%20section%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20meat%20sector%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20meat%20section%3B%2Cc0) are used. It would be pedantic in the extreme to claim that only one means part of an ***economy***, and the other for part of ***company OR a single retail outlet building*** (supermarket or similar). But I'd use ***section*** in the cited context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - so a company's different meat-producing facilities can be together called The company's **meat sector**? Thank you! I could not come up with a search query to find examples.

Comment: **companies have divisions or units or departments, not sectors**. As a former corporate writer, I can attest to that, if you choose to believe me....companies can also have subsidiaries and branches specializing in some product or service....

Comment: Don't assume the terminology is all that precise! It's *feasible* that the vast majority of people who work in large organisations with identifiable "divisions" such as "food, clothing, hardware,..." all use the same words for the same things in this general area, but I seriously doubt that. There's also a ***big*** problem identifying exactly what you mean by something like ***the food division / section / sector*** in the context of a company like, say, Tesco (where some "nationwide" part of the company deals only with food, AND each store has a physical area only concerned with food).

Comment: A company can have a branch, but usually, that means a part of the company in a particular location and does not refer to the product or service. So, ABC Corporation is based in Denver, CO and makes electronics and has a branch in South Bend, IN. This also goes for UK companies. ( I'm leaving this discussion as I will not fight the currents when I've swum in these waters for so long....).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, probably somewhere there is a company that divides itself up into "sectors", but "divisions", "groups", "business units", "product lines", and "departments" are all vastly more common IME.

Comment: @ThePhoton: That's all perfectly true (I did say I personally would use ***section*** in OP's context, if my choices were limited to *section / sector*). But none of that addresses the issue of a nationwide or global ***chain***, where there could easily be some internal ***administrative*** division spread out across a range of physical locations, AND a corresponding ***retail*** division present in every physical location. Everyday English isn't good at making such distinctions, and I doubt any "domain-specific jargon" would be universally understood even within some specific industry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "sector" can indeed be used in the way you describe; i.e. as some sub-division within a company. Here is an example concerning Motorola's former [Semiconductor Products Sector](https://www.eetimes.com/motorola-semiconductor-products-sector-unveils-new-direction-and-structure/#).

In fact, strictly speaking, Motorola SPS wasn't even "within" the company, Motorola, because there *was* not (and still isn't) a single corporate entity called "Motorola". Rather, the sector referred to a set of parts of a group of (very tightly connected) companies spread across different countries -- Motorola, Inc., Motorola GmbH, etc. So in that particular usage, "sector" was more of a trans-corporations term.

As far as I am aware, "sector" has no specific legal meaning, which is in contrast with words like "branch" which can (but doesn't always) mean something more or less precise in legal terms. But as you can see from that article, lack of a formal legal definition doesn't mean it can't be used by the company or others.

Finally: it's probably not a coincidence that in choosing the word "sector", Motorola chose a word more commonly used, as you mention, to describe a portion of an *industry* as a whole.